# Batch file process started by my program doesn't return the full output

Tags: c#, batch-file, process, output

I wrote a batch file that uses [ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) methods that return output to the cmd window.

However, when I start this file as a process from my Windows Forms program (written in C#) the output returned isn't the one in the cmd window.

---

Example:

From the cmd window: "error: no devices/emulators found"

From the output string: "" (No output in this case, different cases- just part of the output).

---

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
return output; // Not the same as the cmd window
```

---

How can I get the full output of this batch file?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you should use

```
process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

**and**

```
process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

***Explanation:***

there's 2 outputs for each application, stdout and stderr

- stdout (STanDard OUTput) is for general purpose output.
- stderr (STanDard ERRor) is for errors.

what seems to happen is that you grab only the stdout of your process, and not the stderr.

you can also want to throw an exception in case you have an error.

something like

```
[...]
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
if(!error.equals("")) 
    throw new Exception(error);
return output;
```